# How to Split string into list in SQL for filtering?

Tags: sql-server

I have a function, where a sentance is passed in. I want to pull data only if the word is found in that sentance. Heres what I have:

```
select 
    word_data
from words
where
    words.word in STRING_SPLIT('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', ' ');
```

Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` returns a dataset, not a scalar value. It goes in the `FROM`. Have you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and its [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-search-by-tag-value)? It demonstrates exactly how to do what you're after.

Comment: Side note: The last "word" in your query will be treated as `'amet.'` *not* `'amet'`. If you have the word `'amet'` in your column `word` it will not be matched.

Comment: to add to what @Larnu said you'll want to handle any punctuation that exists in your string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression have to be like

```sql
SELECT
    [word_data]
FROM
    [words]
WHERE
    [words].[word] IN (
            SELECT
                [value]
            FROM
                STRING_SPLIT('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', ' ')
        );
```

and same result via JOIN

```sql
SELECT
    [word_data]
FROM
    [words]
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            [value]
        FROM
            STRING_SPLIT('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', ' ')
    ) AS [s] ON [s].[value] = [words].[word];
```